# React not setting ref correctly, Uncaught TypeError: current.focus is not a function, can't focus element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

Hello everyone it looks like either I am using the hooks wrong or there's something wrong with my version of react.

I'm on `"react": "16.13.1"` and `"styled-components": "^3.4.10"`

I have the following code:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
`
const StyledInput = styled.input`
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
`

const Input = () => {
  const textInput = useRef(null)

function handleClick() {
  textInput.current.focus()
}

  return (
<StyledDiv onClick={handleClick}>
  <StyledInput ref={textInput}></StyledInput>
</StyledDiv>
  )
}
```

Reproducible code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-river-rzg9w?file=/src/App.js

The idea with this is when the user clicks the div it should focus the input field inside the div. For some reason it is not working. I have tried a couple of other methods, with classes, createRef, and forwardRef, but they all seem to fail on the same way.

If I debug and check the `textInput.current` object I get the following:

```
attrs: {}
context: {__styled-components__next__: {…}, __styled-components-stylesheet__: undefined, __styled-components__: ƒ}
props: {}
refs: {}
state: {theme: null, generatedClassName: "hDTGMK"}
unsubscribeId: -1
updater: {isMounted: ƒ, enqueueSetState: ƒ, enqueueReplaceState: ƒ, enqueueForceUpdate: ƒ}
__reactInternalMemoizedMaskedChildContext: {__styled-components__next__: {…}, __styled-components-stylesheet__: undefined, __styled-components__: ƒ}
__reactInternalMemoizedUnmaskedChildContext: {__styled-components__next__: {…}, router: {…}, __styled-components__: ƒ}
_reactInternalFiber: FiberNode {tag: 1, key: null, stateNode: StyledComponent, elementType: ƒ, type: ƒ, …}
_reactInternalInstance: {_processChildContext: ƒ}
isMounted: (...)
replaceState: (...)
__proto__: BaseStyledComponent
```

When I should be getting something like:

```
accept: ""
accessKey: ""
align: ""
alt: ""
ariaAtomic: null
ariaAutoComplete: null
ariaBusy: null
ariaChecked: null
ariaColCount: null
ariaColIndex: null
ariaColSpan: null
ariaCurrent: null
ariaDescription: null
ariaDisabled: null
ariaExpanded: null
ariaHasPopup: null
ariaHidden: null
ariaKeyShortcuts: null
ariaLabel: "Example Label"
ariaLevel: null
ariaLive: null
ariaModal: null
ariaMultiLine: null
ariaMultiSelectable: null
ariaOrientation: null
ariaPlaceholder: null
ariaPosInSet: null
ariaPressed: null
ariaReadOnly: null
ariaRelevant: null
ariaRequired: null
ariaRoleDescription: null
ariaRowCount: null
ariaRowIndex: null
ariaRowSpan: null
ariaSelected: null
ariaSetSize: null
ariaSort: null
ariaValueMax: null
ariaValueMin: null
ariaValueNow: null
ariaValueText: null
assignedSlot: null
attributeStyleMap: StylePropertyMap {size: 0}
attributes: NamedNodeMap {0: label, 1: placeholder, 2: maxlength, 3: tabindex, 4: aria-label, 5: class, 6: value, label: label, placeholder: placeholder, maxlength: maxlength, tabindex: tabindex, aria-label: aria-label, …}
autocapitalize: ""
autocomplete: ""
autofocus: false
baseURI: "http://localhost:6006/iframe.html?id=input--form-field&viewMode=story"
checked: false
childElementCount: 0
childNodes: NodeList []
children: HTMLCollection []
classList: DOMTokenList(2) ["Input__InputElement-xufccv-0", "jpKLce", value: "Input__InputElement-xufccv-0 jpKLce"]
className: "Input__InputElement-xufccv-0 jpKLce"
clientHeight: 16
clientLeft: 0
clientTop: 0
clientWidth: 340
contentEditable: "inherit"
dataset: DOMStringMap {}
defaultChecked: false
defaultValue: ""
dir: ""
dirName: ""
disabled: false
draggable: false
elementTiming: ""
enterKeyHint: ""
files: null
firstChild: null
firstElementChild: null
form: null
formAction: "http://localhost:6006/iframe.html?id=input--form-field&viewMode=story"
formEnctype: ""
formMethod: ""
formNoValidate: false
formTarget: ""
height: 0
hidden: false
id: ""
incremental: false
indeterminate: false
innerHTML: ""
innerText: ""
inputMode: ""
isConnected: true
isContentEditable: false
labels: NodeList []
lang: ""
lastChild: null
lastElementChild: null
list: null
localName: "input"
max: ""
maxLength: -1
min: ""
minLength: -1
multiple: false
name: ""
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
nextElementSibling: label.Input__InputLabelElement-xufccv-2.ZxOJ
nextSibling: label.Input__InputLabelElement-xufccv-2.ZxOJ
nodeName: "INPUT"
nodeType: 1
nodeValue: null
nonce: ""
offsetHeight: 16
offsetLeft: 15
offsetParent: div.FormInputs__FieldContainer-qnkt4z-0.hRFpsf
offsetTop: 30
offsetWidth: 340
onabort: null
onanimationend: null
onanimationiteration: null
onanimationstart: null
onauxclick: null
onbeforecopy: null
onbeforecut: null
onbeforepaste: null
onbeforexrselect: null
onblur: null
oncancel: null
oncanplay: null
oncanplaythrough: null
onchange: null
onclick: null
onclose: null
oncontextmenu: null
oncopy: null
oncuechange: null
oncut: null
ondblclick: null
ondrag: null
ondragend: null
ondragenter: null
ondragleave: null
ondragover: null
ondragstart: null
ondrop: null
ondurationchange: null
onemptied: null
onended: null
onerror: null
onfocus: null
onformdata: null
onfullscreenchange: null
onfullscreenerror: null
ongotpointercapture: null
oninput: null
oninvalid: null
onkeydown: null
onkeypress: null
onkeyup: null
onload: null
onloadeddata: null
onloadedmetadata: null
onloadstart: null
onlostpointercapture: null
onmousedown: null
onmouseenter: null
onmouseleave: null
onmousemove: null
onmouseout: null
onmouseover: null
onmouseup: null
onmousewheel: null
onpaste: null
onpause: null
onplay: null
onplaying: null
onpointercancel: null
onpointerdown: null
onpointerenter: null
onpointerleave: null
onpointermove: null
onpointerout: null
onpointerover: null
onpointerrawupdate: null
onpointerup: null
onprogress: null
onratechange: null
onreset: null
onresize: null
onscroll: null
onsearch: null
onseeked: null
onseeking: null
onselect: null
onselectionchange: null
onselectstart: null
onstalled: null
onsubmit: null
onsuspend: null
ontimeupdate: null
ontoggle: null
ontransitioncancel: null
ontransitionend: null
ontransitionrun: null
ontransitionstart: null
onvolumechange: null
onwaiting: null
onwebkitanimationend: null
onwebkitanimationiteration: null
onwebkitanimationstart: null
onwebkitfullscreenchange: null
onwebkitfullscreenerror: null
onwebkittransitionend: null
onwheel: null
outerHTML: "<input label="Example Label" placeholder="Placeholder" maxlength="" tabindex="0" aria-label="Example Label" class="Input__InputElement-xufccv-0 jpKLce" value="">"
outerText: ""
ownerDocument: document
parentElement: div.Input__InputWrapper-xufccv-1.bbwaki
parentNode: div.Input__InputWrapper-xufccv-1.bbwaki
part: DOMTokenList [value: ""]
pattern: ""
placeholder: "Placeholder"
prefix: null
previousElementSibling: null
previousSibling: null
readOnly: false
required: false
scrollHeight: 16
scrollLeft: 0
scrollTop: 0
scrollWidth: 340
selectionDirection: "none"
selectionEnd: 0
selectionStart: 0
shadowRoot: null
size: 20
slot: ""
spellcheck: true
src: ""
step: ""
style: CSSStyleDeclaration {alignContent: "", alignItems: "", alignSelf: "", alignmentBaseline: "", all: "", …}
tabIndex: 0
tagName: "INPUT"
textContent: ""
title: ""
translate: true
type: "text"
useMap: ""
validationMessage: ""
validity: ValidityState {valueMissing: false, typeMismatch: false, patternMismatch: false, tooLong: false, tooShort: false, …}
value: (...)
valueAsDate: null
valueAsNumber: NaN
webkitEntries: []
webkitdirectory: false
width: 0
willValidate: true
__reactEventHandlers$ko5j6dgwro: {label: "Example Label", placeholder: "Placeholder", value: "", onChange: ƒ, onBlur: ƒ, …}
__reactInternalInstance$ko5j6dgwro: FiberNode {tag: 5, key: null, elementType: "input", type: "input", stateNode: input.Input__InputElement-xufccv-0.jpKLce, …}
_valueTracker: {getValue: ƒ, setValue: ƒ, stopTracking: ƒ}
_wrapperState: {initialChecked: undefined, initialValue: "", controlled: true}
get value: ƒ ()
set value: ƒ (value)
__proto__: HTMLInputElement
```

Has anyone run into something like this or know what's going on here? 16.13 should have hooks... so I'm unsure on what's going on here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From styled-components docs:

> Using an older version of styled-components (below 4.0.0) or of React?
> Use the innerRef prop instead.

So, you should change to this:

```
<StyledDiv onClick={handleClick}>
  <StyledInput innerRef={textInput}></StyledInput>
</StyledDiv>
```